# Deploy Project option not available at project level for SharePoint 2013 project in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, sharepoint-2013

I have recently upgraded my SharePoint 2010 solution to SharePoint 2013 and in the same process upgraded the solution as well to Visual-Studio 2012.

One of the things I have observed is that I don't have the "deploy" option at each SharePoint project level. On digging a bit further I have noticed that the "deloy" option is available to all projects under solution but not for projects under any folder.

e.g. I have attached the image showing the solution structure containing two projects. As seen the "deploy" option is not available for the project under the folder.

[image]

Is this a bug or is there something setting in VS to make this work?

-Sharath

Comment: Just an additional information, I am using the VS 2012 Ultimate
Version 11.0.51106.01 Update 1
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.5.50709

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the very definition of a bug.

See also http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointgeneral/thread/199f8fdb-afbd-4c40-b28c-beba6fc41fbf/

Update 2 - and still no fix.

Edit: Fun fact. If you select two or more projects - the deploy option re-appears -.-

Comment: @Muhammedh You actually don't have to use a dummy project - you can simply select both the project and the containing folder to have the "Deploy Selection" option appear.

Comment: @AndersFjeldstad Thanks for the tip :-)! Helped me from creating a bunch of unnecessary projects.

Comment: @AndersFjeldstad Just realized tht if we have more than 1 project in the folder (which is true most of the times) it deployed all the projects under the folder. can you confirm this please??

Comment: @Muhammedh That's probably true. So if that's your situation and you really don't want to deploy them all, you might have to go with the dummy project workaround (or dummy folder - haven't tried this).

Comment: @AndersFjeldstad I actually went ahead with the dummy project and moved it around..